# Where in MYSQL are data actually stored (innodb)?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I checked the datadir variable inside de conf. file my.cnf and it is /var/lib/mysql.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL by default stores its data files in /var/lib/mysql directory.

But if the default location has been changed then you can use grep to find the folder.

Simply run the following command in the terminal:

```
grep datadir /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment: datadir is not your data directory that`s why grep is used to find the actual datadir folder. Kindly read answer carefully.

Comment: the command you specified just returned the datadir ( e.g. /var/lib/mysql ) and i already said that this cannot be the one containing data